# Event Loop in Node.js and database access

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, rest

I've been reading some information about Node.js and have a particular question.
Let me try to explain it using the following example:

```
model.book.findOne({'Id': request.params.Id}, null, function (err, book) {
   if (err || book== null) {
      //Do some error handling
   }

   //Rating calculation happens here (add new rating and calculate the average)
   //Something like book.ratings.push(...)

   book.save(function (err) {
       if (err) {
           console.log(err);
       }
       return reply(book);
   });
}
```

Users can do a rest call to my server where they can rate a book in the database (MongoDb in this case). What happens if 2 users do the same rest request really close in time between eachother? Can the following happen:

- User1 does a rest request
- User1 gets the book by id from the db
- User1 starts doing the rating calculation
- User2 does a rest request
- User2 gets the book by id from the db
- User1 is done doing the calculation and saves the book
- User2 starts doing the rating calculation (does not have the new rating by user 1)
- User2 is done doing the calculation and saves the book

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Jdruwe Mongodb supports Atomic operations within the documents, so you don't need to worry about the writes

Comment: Looks like you're using Mongoose. If so, Mongoose's `push` is atomic (see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21549755)), so you don't have to worry about concurrent writes.

Comment: Does this mean that the book object returned by the callback can be safely edited and saved without caring about other requests?

Comment: Well, all operations in Mongo within a document is atomic however, if the calculations are done in memory (as i guess in this case when the book object is loaded and then some manipulations are done) this have high chances of ending up in error scenario if not coded properly...

Comment: Yea I was thinking the same so I decided to use findOneAndUpdate.